# How do I get latest tweet by specific user and specific hashtag

Tags: twitter

May I know how do I get latest tweet by specific user and specific hashtag

On twitter **[GET Search](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search)** no parameters option for the username or userid

Let's say I want to search tweet from username `stackoverflow` with `#php` hashtag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to custom code the second part.

1. Use https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline - to get the latest tweets from a specific user.
2. Write Code to search within the response Object of (1) with the hashtag (search-key).